# Old GC starting immediately after previous collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, concurrent-mark-sweep

I am facing a peculiar problem where Old garbage collection is starting immediately after previous collection.

```
2018-04-15T13:07:30.028+0530: 51251.379: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:30.028+0530: 51251.379: [ParNew: 277743K->6502K(306688K), 0.0103550 secs] 3494143K->3223365K(4160256K) icms_dc=0 , 0.0104470 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:30.133+0530: 51251.485: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:30.134+0530: 51251.485: [ParNew: 279142K->7017K(306688K), 0.0116990 secs] 3496005K->3224540K(4160256K) icms_dc=3 , 0.0117880 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:30.193+0530: 51251.544: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3217522K(3853568K)] 3357051K(4160256K), 0.0675390 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:30.261+0530: 51251.612: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2018-04-15T13:07:30.313+0530: 51251.664: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:30.313+0530: 51251.664: [ParNew: 279657K->7381K(306688K), 0.0114140 secs] 3497180K->3225699K(4160256K) icms_dc=5 , 0.0115040 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:30.418+0530: 51251.770: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:30.418+0530: 51251.770: [ParNew: 280021K->8081K(306688K), 0.0111750 secs] 3498339K->3227227K(4160256K) icms_dc=7 , 0.0112640 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:30.524+0530: 51251.875: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:30.524+0530: 51251.875: [ParNew: 280721K->8309K(306688K), 0.0113970 secs] 3499867K->3228238K(4160256K) icms_dc=8 , 0.0114890 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:30.635+0530: 51251.986: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:30.635+0530: 51251.986: [ParNew: 280949K->9978K(306688K), 0.0115520 secs] 3500878K->3230800K(4160256K) icms_dc=8 , 0.0116420 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:30.756+0530: 51252.107: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:30.756+0530: 51252.107: [ParNew: 282618K->8169K(306688K), 0.0117060 secs] 3503440K->3229988K(4160256K) icms_dc=9 , 0.0117920 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.366+0530: 51258.717: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.761/7.105 secs] [Times: user=28.04 sys=7.90, real=7.10 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.366+0530: 51258.717: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.443+0530: 51258.794: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:37.443+0530: 51258.794: [ParNew: 282467K->9766K(306688K), 0.0135960 secs] 3553874K->3282587K(4160256K) icms_dc=12 , 0.0137020 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.642+0530: 51258.993: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:37.642+0530: 51258.993: [ParNew: 282406K->9653K(306688K), 0.0136870 secs] 3555227K->3283930K(4160256K) icms_dc=12 , 0.0137950 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.732+0530: 51259.083: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.028/0.367 secs] [Times: user=1.00 sys=0.11, real=0.37 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.732+0530: 51259.083: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.818+0530: 51259.170: [GC2018-04-15T13:07:37.818+0530: 51259.170: [ParNew: 282293K->13539K(306688K), 0.0142290 secs] 3556570K->3289101K(4160256K) icms_dc=12 , 0.0143440 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.917+0530: 51259.268: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.036/0.185 secs] [Times: user=0.45 sys=0.35, real=0.18 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.918+0530: 51259.269: [GC[YG occupancy: 168145 K (306688 K)]2018-04-15T13:07:37.918+0530: 51259.269: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0656650 secs]2018-04-15T13:07:37.983+0530: 51259.335: [weak refs processing, 0.0017590 secs]2018-04-15T13:07:37.985+0530: 51259.336: [scrub string table, 0.0006280 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 3275561K(3853568K)] 3443707K(4160256K), 0.0682330 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.06, real=0.07 secs]
2018-04-15T13:07:37.986+0530: 51259.337: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.052+0530: 51324.403: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.052+0530: 51324.403: [ParNew: 279898K->6077K(306688K), 0.0127900 secs] 1501235K->1228195K(4160256K) icms_dc=12 , 0.0128800 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.099+0530: 51324.450: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 7.128/65.112 secs] [Times: user=287.93 sys=82.16, real=65.12 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.099+0530: 51324.450: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.134+0530: 51324.485: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.134+0530: 51324.486: [ParNew: 278717K->6064K(306688K), 0.0132430 secs] 1500835K->1229047K(4160256K) icms_dc=12 , 0.0133360 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.217+0530: 51324.568: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.217+0530: 51324.568: [ParNew: 278704K->7259K(306688K), 0.0130970 secs] 1501687K->1231046K(4160256K) icms_dc=12 , 0.0131950 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.264+0530: 51324.616: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.017/0.166 secs] [Times: user=0.91 sys=0.70, real=0.16 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.299+0530: 51324.650: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.299+0530: 51324.650: [ParNew: 279899K->6120K(306688K), 0.0126340 secs] 1503686K->1230747K(4160256K) icms_dc=7 , 0.0127230 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.02, real=0.01 secs]


2018-04-15T13:08:43.343+0530: 51324.694: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1224626K(3853568K)] 1357563K(4160256K), 0.0601220 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.403+0530: 51324.755: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.441+0530: 51324.792: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.441+0530: 51324.792: [ParNew: 278760K->7322K(306688K), 0.0131820 secs] 1503387K->1232788K(4160256K) icms_dc=7 , 0.0132770 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.526+0530: 51324.877: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.526+0530: 51324.877: [ParNew: 279962K->6368K(306688K), 0.0131880 secs] 1505428K->1232636K(4160256K) icms_dc=7 , 0.0132780 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.608+0530: 51324.959: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.608+0530: 51324.959: [ParNew: 279008K->7666K(306688K), 0.0126730 secs] 1505276K->1234797K(4160256K) icms_dc=7 , 0.0127770 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.691+0530: 51325.042: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.691+0530: 51325.042: [ParNew: 280306K->6428K(306688K), 0.0135520 secs] 1507437K->1234370K(4160256K) icms_dc=7 , 0.0136350 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.02, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.774+0530: 51325.125: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.774+0530: 51325.125: [ParNew: 279068K->7766K(306688K), 0.0134430 secs] 1507010K->1236538K(4160256K) icms_dc=7 , 0.0135200 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
2018-04-15T13:08:43.856+0530: 51325.207: [GC2018-04-15T13:08:43.856+0530: 51325.207: [ParNew: 280406K->7712K(306688K), 0.0136040 secs] 1509178K->1237349K(4160256K) icms_dc=7 , 0.0136830 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

The old generation is only 30% occupied after the previous collection as evident from the Inital mark. Can somebody please explain this ?
Also, as a result of this my request queue got filled up

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` to show the cause of GCs (requires java8 or newer). And you seem to be using iCMS, that's deprecated and has been removed in newer versions and there rarely was a reason to unless you're using an single-core system.

Comment: I understand that. But I need to know the possible reasons for this behavior in java 1.7